# Ignite client node wants to connect to cassandra layer

Tags: java, caching, cassandra, ignite

I have several server nodes of Apache Ignite, connected to cassandra db.
Nodes works fine.
Now I have to connect client nodes to this cluster. But clients nodes have not network connectivity with cassandra db and while initializing they can not to start work.

As far as I see connection is used for validate driver, because then all activities are done through caches and servers nodes.

My case is to disable connect or validate to cassandra db from clients node.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an atomic cache, you can try to provide different cache configuration on server and client (with and without store).

For transactional cache store is required on clients though, because it updates the store from the node which runs a transaction.

Comment: Thanks, Valentin. Cache is atomic, but works execute on server through ignite.execute :).
I have solved problem.It is my fault. I have written persistent layer(CacheStore) and forget delete manual connect initialization.
Sry. :)